# C# - Transformar CUIL/CUIT numerico pasandole a string y agregandole los 2 guiones (-) que lleva

Tags: c#, mvc, string

quisiera saber cual es la mejor forma para poder hacer lo siguiente en C#
Recibo los CUIL/CUIT de la siguiente forma numerica. Ejemplo: 20354002003
y quisiera pasarlo a string y a su vez agregarle los dos guines que lleva y que quede de la forma: 20-35400200-3

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un montón de maneras de resolver ese problema, una, podría ser transformarlo a `Long` y luego formatearlo con el método [`ToString(string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#:%7E:text=The%20ToString(String)%20method%20formats,conventions%20of%20the%20current%20culture.)

Por ejemplo:

```
var t = Convert.ToInt64("20354002003");     
Console.WriteLine(t.ToString("##-########-#"));
```

De esta manera, el resultado sería

> 20-35400200-3

Otra posibilidad, sería la de trabajar directamente con la cadena con el método [`Substring`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1), por ejemplo:

```
string t = "20354002003";
Console.WriteLine($"{t.Substring(0,2)}-{t.Substring(2,8)}-{t[10]}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar la librería https://github.com/pixelario/CUIT

```
Install-Package Pixelario.CUIT -Version 0.10.0
```

Tiene varias opciones ToString

Ejemplo:

```
var cuit = CUIT.Parse("20270010017");
Console.WriteLine(cuit.ToString()); // 20270010017
Console.WriteLine(cuit.ToString("guion")); // 20-27001001-7
Console.WriteLine(cuit.ToString("hyphen")); // 20-27001001-7
Console.WriteLine(cuit.ToString("punto")); // 20.27001001.7
Console.WriteLine(cuit.ToString("dot")); // 20.27001001.7
Console.WriteLine(cuit.ToString("espacio")); // 20 27001001 7
Console.WriteLine(cuit.ToString("space")); // 20 27001001 7
```